# Copying Element: Reference doesn't change

Tags: java, copy

I'm trying to copy a source element into an existing destination element. It works fine in the method but the reference in the main method doesn't change. What is my mistake?

```
public class Bounds {
    public static <T extends Number> void copy(Paar<? extends Number> src, Paar<? extends Number> dst) {
        // src = (1, 2) dst = (1.1, 2.2)
        T c1 = (T) src.p1;
        T c2 = (T) src.p2;
        dst = new Paar<>(c1, c2);

        System.out.println("Src:" + src);
        System.out.println("Dst:" + dst);
        // src = (1, 2) dst = (1, 2)    
    }
}
```

```
public class BoundsMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] iFeld = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Number[] nFeld = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };
        Paar<Integer> src = new Paar<>(iFeld[0], iFeld[1]);
        Paar<Number> dst = new Paar<>(nFeld[0], nFeld[1]);

        System.out.println("src=" + src + "\ndst vor copy =" + dst );
        // src = (1, 2) dst = (1.1, 2.2)

        Bounds.copy(src, dst);
        System.out.println("src nach copy =" + src);
        System.out.println("dst nach copy =" + dst);
        // src = (1, 2) dst = (1.1, 2.2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is java pass by value or pass by reference?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40507/2310289